# The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist

Tags: asp.net

i am gettin g this error. i just do not understand why it is happening. my site map file is in root of my site. i doubt that my site map file name is not Web.sitemap rather i gave the name BBASite.sitemap.

my sitemap file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<siteMapNode url="~/DE/index.aspx" title="DE Home"  description="DE Home">
  <siteMapNode url="~/DE/Parts.aspx" title="Part"  description="DE Part" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/DE/SubParts.aspx" title="Subpart"  description="DE Subpart" />
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode url="~/US/index.aspx" title="US Home"  description="US Home">
  <siteMapNode url="~/US/Parts.aspx" title="Part"  description="US Part" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/US/SubParts.aspx" title="Subpart"  description="US Subpart" />
</siteMapNode>

<siteMapNode url="~/UK/index.aspx" title="UK Home"  description="UK Home">
  <siteMapNode url="~/UK/Parts.aspx" title="Part"  description="UK Part" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/UK/SubParts.aspx" title="Subpart"  description="UK Subpart" />
</siteMapNode>

 </siteMapNode>
 </siteMap>
```

if my site map file name is different then what i need to do....plzz advise. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your web.config file. Probably in the XmlSitemapProvider there is a reference to the web.sitemap file.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the `BBASite.sitemap` file. Name of [sitemap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178426.aspx) file must be `web.sitemap`.